# Jenkins Editable email notification no longer sending emails

Tags: email, jenkins

I have a job that aggregates and emails out unit test results as html reports. This job used to work, sending out an email on both success and failure. Recently it stopped sending emails, the only configuration changes I made were to add email recipients (total of 3), and schedule the job on a timer. The job still runs as scheduled and says emails are triggered, but none are being sent. The only error message is to say one of the report directories doesn't exist, but in the past that has not prevented the email from sending. Went to the global configuration and the "test email" function, I received that email just fine. Password was due for an update, I reset it, changed it in the global configuration for the plugin, still got the test email but no emails from the job. Is there another config field I'm missing somewhere? And why would the job suddenly stop sending things on its own? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Which plugin are you using for emails?

Comment: Email Extension plugin

Comment: Go to **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** and under the Advance section of the Extended E-mail Notification section enable the **Enable Debug Mode** checkbox - then you can see the exact error in your jobs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.